# Binding jquery AutoComplete dropdown list to menu items

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, menuitem, jquery-ui-autocomplete

There is a dropdown list data as seen in the first picture. Once I click one of the items in the list, it does not bind with the sidebar left menu-list. I would like to make it as seen in the second picture. Once clicked, it should search through menu-list and find one. yet I use the below code and wondering if there is a feature of Jquery to do it.

note: somehow it works with google autocomplete feature.

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#leftMenuSearch").autocomplete({
      source: list,
      minLength: 0,
      select: function (event, ui) {
        // that's how get the menu reference:
      }
    }).click(function () {
      console.log("this", this)
      $(this).autocomplete('search', "");
    });
  });
```

First Picture

[image: First Picture]

Second Picture

[image: Second Picture]

Comment: Sounds like you want to filter a existing list not create a autocomplete list.

Comment: @Twisty yes I already created an autocomplete list. however it does not collabarate with filter. When I choose an item among autocomplete list, filter does not work somehow.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Twisty there you go  [link](https://jsfiddle.net/cagatay07/0etwoanv/7/) if you type spiderman in search area, it works however if you choose from localStorage dropdown list, it does not trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure what you want is a filter and not Autocomplete.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/Lu57qpxh/11/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  function filterTable(tbl, term) {
    $("tbody tr", tbl).show();
    $("tbody tr", tbl).each(function(i, r) {
      if ($("td:eq(0)", r).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(term) < 0) {
        $(r).hide();
      }
    });
  }

  $("#txtsearch").keyup(function() {
    var t = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    filterTable($("table"), t);
  });
});
```

This Shows or Hides items in the table based on the Search Term.

**Update**

If you want to use this with AutoComplete, you can do this.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/Lu57qpxh/22/

```
$(function() {
  function filterTable(tbl, term) {
    $("tbody tr", tbl).show();
    $("tbody tr", tbl).each(function(i, r) {
      if ($("td:eq(0)", r).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) < 0) {
        $(r).hide();
      }
    });
  }

  $("#txtsearch").autocomplete({
    source: ["Spiderman", "Wonder", "hata"],
    select: function(e, ui) {
      filterTable($("table"), ui.item.value);
    }
  }).keyup(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
      $("table tbody tr").show();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: you removed autoComplete function. yes filtering should be there however I would like to use autocomplete list together with filtering.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to get it applicable for my code however I have div instead of table-td -tr, it is like that   `<div class=​"objectText" style=​"display:​ none;​">​Çalışanlar​</div>​` I could not achieve to equal with 'çalışanlar'

Comment: I tried  `$("ul li a div", tbl).show();
        $("ul li a div", tbl).each(function (i, r) {
          if ($("div:eq(0)", r).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) < 0) {
            console.log("div",r);
            console.log("toLowerCase",$("div:eq(0)", r).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()));
            $(r).hide();
          }
        });`
As it is linear is like ul-li-a-div @Twisty

Comment: @chatay I would advise checking it out more on your own. If you continue to have a problem, can post a new question.